# Magento 2 - How to remove "Add new MODEL" button on \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container

Tags: magento2, grid, widget

I am extending the \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Container with my block, and I want to remove the button for adding new instances of this model ("MODEL"). How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Call **removeButton('add')** from the *_construct* method of your Adminhtml Block file ...

*app\code\YourSpace\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml\Whatever.php*

```
namespace YourSpace\YourModule\Block\Adminhtml;

protected function _construct()
{
    ...

    parent::_construct();

    $this->removeButton('add');
}

...
```